# How to check if my Android app is blocked to start on system boot?

Tags: android

I have created android app which starts on system boot and works like a charm but I want to add protection if user blocks autostart this application by third party apps like CCleaner or Clean Master etc.
The only thing I want to know is information that my application is blocked to autostart and display this once user open configuration page. I'm not going to change this settings. Of course this should be done from the code perspective not by third party application.

Does someone know where I can find this information?

Regards,
DM

Comment: I would guess that those apps just use the `PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting()` to disable an app's boot Receiver, since they need root; at least Clean Master does, anyway. If that's the case, then you can just check the enabled state of your app's boot Receiver with `PackageManager#getComponentEnabledSetting()`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

`getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName);`


returns integer status with info if receiver (described as a componentName) is enabled or disabled. Moreover changing this status from the code is also possible.

Comment: Yeah, your app can always enable and disable its own components, but you would need root access to change another package's components' states.

Answer (score 0):

Following code resolved my problem (unfortunately works only for Android < 6.0)

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyBootCompletedReceiver.class);
int state = getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName);

if (state != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED && state != PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT) {
 // ALERT that Receiver is blocked -> works for Android < 6.0
}
```